# Segmentation Fault in Binary Search

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This code has no problem without `QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);` and `QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);` functions. Also when I use this functions with a sequential search program it works too. I could not figure out what is the problem here. Why I get segmentation fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
LARGE_INTEGER start;
LARGE_INTEGER end;
double interval;

int i, c, first, last, middle, n, search, array[20000];

FILE *fptr;

//read sorted list file!
if((fptr = fopen("sorted.txt","r"))==NULL){
printf("Error in reading file !\n");
return 0;
}
//array of sorted list!
while(!feof(fptr)){
if(!feof(fptr)){
fscanf(fptr,"%d",&array[i]);
i++;}

}


printf("Enter value to find\n");
scanf("%d",&search);


first = 0;
last = 20000 - 1;
middle = (first+last)/2;

QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

while( first <= last )
{
  if ( array[middle] < search )
     first = middle + 1;    
  else if ( array[middle] == search ) 
  {
     printf("%d found at location %d.\n", search, middle+1);
     break;
  }
  else
     last = middle - 1;

  middle = (first + last)/2;
}
if ( first > last )
  printf("Not found! %d is not present in the list.\n", search);

  QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
interval = (double) (end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / frequency.QuadPart;

printf("%f\n", interval);

system("pause");

return 0;   
}
```

Comment: And an evil `#define LARGE_INTEGER char` and your code's broken :P

Comment: Have you used a debugger and tried to narrow down the problem?

Comment: Just a side note here - you should be setting `last = i - 1`, not `20000 - 1`. This assumes of course that `i < 20000`.  If you use 20000, you are searching on invalid items.

Comment: while(!feof(ptr)) if(!feof(ptr))

Comment: Another side note - binary searches require **sorted** arrays. From your code comments, your array is unsorted.

Comment: Thanks for the side notes. I editted my comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you are never defining i to something yet have a i++. At least that is the error I get when I try this code.

Comment: +1 That's a good point. it's been so long since I've done C. I forget about those uninitialized variables...

Comment: That was a really good point. When I initialized it, worked. You have been a big help.